# Javascript logical operators

Tags: javascript, integer

I am trying to write a lottery game where the numbers 3, 5, 8 entered into the 3 separate text boxes will yield a success alert box, and otherwise a fail alert box which also shows the wrong numbers entered.

I've put the code here but I'm lost as to why it isn't working!

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9MsCY/4/

```
//correct numbers
var a1 = 3;
var a2 = 5;
var a3 = 8;

function mainGame(num1, num2, num3) {

   var num1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById("b").value;
   var num3 = document.getElementById("c").value;

   var a = num1;
   var b = num2;
   var c = num3;

   if (isUnique(a,b,c)) {

       if (checkGuess(a,b,c)) {
            alert("Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct, you've won £1000!");
       } else {
            alert("Better luck next time. Your numbers are "+a+" , "+b+" , "+c"");
       }
    }
 }

//function in while loop to check for unique numbers and for not null
function isUnique() {

    var len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] == null || arguments[i] = arguments[i-1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//compare inputs with correct numbers
function checkGuess () {
    if (a == 3 && b == 5 && c == 8) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The `<font>` tag? The `<center>` tag? What is this, 1996??

Comment: Can you please ask a concrete question? _"Not working_" isn't a one.

Comment: @gdoron - All we're missing in this one is blink and marquee.

Comment: Your `onclick` calls `myCheck()` which doesn't exist.

Comment: `"Better luck next time. Your numbers are "+a+" , "+b+" , "+c""` <-- two extra quotes?

Comment: You have plenty of syntax errors, use jshint.com

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of syntax errors. Best way to debug javascript code is to write html + js, browse your page in chrome browser and use chrome developer tools. It will point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above your code has syntax errors.  I have removed it and working now.

Check this suit for your application logic    http://jsfiddle.net/btYpQ/

```
`/function in while loop to check for unique numbers and for not null
function isUnique() {
var len = arguments.length;
for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
   if (arguments[i] == null || arguments[i] == arguments[i-1]) {
    return false;
   }
 }
        return true;
}


//compare inputs with correct numbers
function checkGuess () {

if (a == 3 && b == 5 && c == 8) {
   return true;
   }
   return false;

}
function mainGame() {

var num1 = document.getElementById("a").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("b").value;
var num3 = document.getElementById("c").value;

var a = num1;
var b = num2;
var c = num3;


if (isUnique(a,b,c)) {

    if (checkGuess(a,b,c)) {
        alert("Congratulations! You got all 3 numbers correct, you've won £1000!");
 }   
        else {
        alert("Better luck next time. Your numbers are "+a+" , "+b+" , "+c);
        }
}



}

window.onload=function(){
//correct numbers

var a1 = 3;
var a2 = 5;
var a3 = 8; 


}//]]>   `
```